# How to fix problem with setting swiper position in the middle of div

Tags: sass, media-queries

I'm trying to set swiper in the middle of the div container, it looks like it's working just for iphone 5 width. I set up my one class for it but it doesn't work. Could anyone explain to me how to fix it?

html file

```
  <swiper class="align-middle" #swiper [config]="swiperconfig">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data;">
          <div class="swiper-slide align-middle" >
              <app-ds-widget-component #card [item]="item" [totalFlow]="data.totalFlow"></app-ds-widget-component>
          </div>

      </ng-container>
  </swiper>
</div>
```

scss file

```
@media (min-width: 570px) and (max-width: 1024px){
  .swiper-view {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

  }
}
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
  .swiper-view {
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
}
```

Comment: If you can create the fiddle that will be helpful.

Comment: Yep I know it might be helpful but fiddle doesn't have angular in options and stackblitz show me an error with swiper. I don't know well these tools :(